# Angular6 - Store a user variable in a service and access it from other components without it being undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular6, webstorm

So I'm making an Angular app and at one point I want to store a user variable (that I got from an async call to Firestore Cloud), the variable is indeed set (checked with console.log()) but when I switch pages and try to load that user's recipes on Firestore it says my user variable is undefined.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks

EDIT: Code

```
tryConnect(email: string, password: string) {
// u = array of users
this.usersWithId.subscribe(u => {
  for (const a of u) {
    console.log(a);
    if (a.email === email && a.password === password) {
      this.connectedUser = a;
      console.log(this.connectedUser);
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

}

```
addRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
console.log(this.connectedUser);
this.db.collection('/recipes').add({
  name: recipe.name,
  description: recipe.description,
  meal: recipe.meal,
  steps: recipe.steps,
  servings: recipe.servings,
  cuisine: recipe.cuisine,
  userID: this.connectedUser.userID,
  ingredients: recipe.ingredients
});
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: @Brandon I'm not at home right now but I will when I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you want to do should be achieved via `rxjs/store` or similar. Rxjs/store is a state management system where you can store anything across your app and it will be up to date anywhere you use it.

Also as an option is to use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` if you want to save it across the sessions.

Comment: Ah right! I've used localstorage before but for some reason it didn't come to mind in this situation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use **[`@angular/fire`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)**, if you're not already using it.

Here's how you can leverage `@angular/fire` to achieve what you're trying.

`AngularFireAuth` when injected as a dependency has an `authState` which is of type `Observable<firebase.User>`. This essentially has the state of your currently logged in user.

Now, in your service, you can create a private `BehaviorSubject<Observable<firebase.User>>` on which, `next` will be called as soon as your `authState` changes.

You can then expose this `BehaviourSubject<firebase.User>` `asObservable`. This the Observable is public, whosoever injects your service as a dependency will have access to `user$` and subscribe to it to get the state of the currently logged in user.

Here's how it would look like in code:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '@app/shared/models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private user: BehaviorSubject<Observable<firebase.User>> = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<firebase.User>>(null);
  user$ = this.user.asObservable().pipe(switchMap(user => user));

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
    this.user.next(this.afAuth.authState);
  }

  loginViaCredentails(user: User) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: I am using @angular/fire & I'd read about that way of authenticatinh users but as I understood it, it was more of a way to login users into the database than into my app (it would check against the accounts created in the Firestore Console). Is that correct?